# Apache Ant Installation In Mac

Tags: macos, ant

I installed ant using home brew.
Now the `ant -version` gives me the installed version, but how do i find out where ant is installed on my mac?

Kindly help?

Comment: Check this article to see if that helps - https://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-apache-ant-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is better suited for https://apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brew is going to put a symlink in `/usr/local/bin/`that points to the installation in `/usr/local/Cellar/ant/`

To find the complete path:
 `ls -l $(which ant)`